# Как проверить, выполнилась ли функция в js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Добрый день.** 
Подскажите как проверить выполнилась ли функция в js?

**P.S.** 
Есть AJAX запрос в success еще один AJAX с еще одним success. 
Вне AJAX есть функция, которую нужно выполнить по завершению второго AJAX.

Comment: Проверку выполнения какой функции из трех перечисленных нужно осуществить?

Comment: Poul, Проверять вторую функцию success на завершенность

Comment: А что мешает во втором `success` ее запустить?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Но если он связан с синхронностью выполнения то смотрите в сторону промисов или колбек функций.

Comment: Так запихните ее вызов в конец второго success

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev 1) Это плодит вложенность (у меня уже 5-6 вложенных аяксов:O ) 2) Мне необходим вызов функции после выполнения success аякса, так как мой последующий аякс запрос выполняется асинхронно с прошлым, он неуспевает получить данные из прошлого

Comment: @FrogFrogov тогда вам точно пора на промисы переходить, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/